# Jacoco coverage report XML file not generated on Android

Tags: android, jacoco

I am trying to generate Android UnitTest coverage report XML file by using Jacoco, to display it on SonarQube webpage.

Here is what I did.

(1) Added Jacoco dependency in project build.gradle.

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.8.4"
    }
}
```

(2) Applied Jacoco plugin in build.gradle(app).

```
plugins {
    id 'jacoco'
}
```

(3) Configured the plugin to output test reports in the XML format required by SonarQube

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    jacoco.includeNoLocationClasses = true
    jacoco.excludes = ['jdk.internal.*']
}

task codeCoverageReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: 'test') {
    group = "Reporting"
    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports after running tests."
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        xml.required = true
    }
    def androidExclusion = [
            '**/databinding/**/*.*',
            '**/android/databinding/*Binding.*',
            '**/BR.*',
            '**/R.*',
            '**/R$*.*',
            '**/BuildConfig.*',
            '**/Manifest*.*',
            '**/*_MembersInjector.*',
            '**/*Dagger*.*',
            '**/Dagger*Component.*',
            '**/Dagger*Component$Builder.*',
            '**/*Module_*Factory.*',
            '**/*Fragment*.*',
            '**/*Activity*.*',
            '**/*Adapter*.*',
            '**/*ViewPager*.*',
            '**/*ViewHolder*.*',
            '**/*Module*.*',
            '**/*_Factory*.*',
            '**/*Companion*.*',
            '**/*MapperImpl*.*',
            '**/*$ViewInjector*.*',
            '**/*$ViewBinder*.*',
            '**/*Component*.*',
            '**/*$Lambda$*.*',
            '**/*Module*.*',
            '**/*Hilt*.*',
            '**/*MembersInjector*.*',
            '**/*_Provide*Factory*.*',
            '**/*Extensions*.*',
            '**/*$*'
    ]

    def javaClasses = fileTree(
            dir: "$project.buildDir/intermediates/javac/debug",  // Path to java classes
            excludes: androidExclusion
    )

    def kotlinClasses = fileTree(
            dir: "$project.buildDir/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug",
            excludes: androidExclusion
    )

    classDirectories.from = files([javaClasses, kotlinClasses])
    sourceDirectories.from = files("$project.projectDir/src/main/java")
    executionData.from = files('build/jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec')
}
```

(4) Ran generating report file task on Terminal.

```
 % ./gradlew codeCoverageReport
```

The result is as below.
Only html file is generated.
I need XML file matchable with SonarQube format.

How can I create coverage report file suitable with SonarQube format.
Thank you.

[image: Result of Terminal command]